# Node.js | Remove element in json

Tags: node.js, express

I have a json like this:

```
var myjson = [
{
    "id": "1"
},
{
    "id": "2"
},
{
    "id": "3"
},
{
    "id": "4"
},
{
    "id": "5"
}
];
```

I want the incoming id removed from myjson when app.delete() is triggered.

Forexample incoming id = 3. Then myjson's new look:

```
var myjson = [
    {
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "id": "4"
    },
    {
        "id": "5"
    }
    ];
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` to do this like the code below:

```js
const removeItem = (id) => myjson.filter(item => item !== id);
```